# Using MySql Statment, How can I select random 10 row from 100 limit?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, mariadb

I have met one problem that required me to run the query to select the data 10 records randomly among 100 records(limit 100) which total records of my table is up to 9000 records.

Do you guys have any ideas on this problem?.

Comment: which hundred records?  You have up to 9000, you want 10, what does it mean to be among 100 records?

Comment: @DanielFarrell For example we get only top 100 records follow our condition. Then we want to get 10 randomly among that top 100.

Comment: Please check my modified solution.

Comment: How is this different from just choosing a random 10 rows?

Comment: We just want to get 100 records with the specific condition => then those 100 records  were random to select 10 records  to display on the UI. To do like this, the UI will always display different data. @GordonLinoff

Comment: @LeangSocheat . . . A random sample of size 10 from a random sample of size 100 is the same thing as a random sample of size 10 from all the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fetch 100 rows and get random 10 rows using this query.

**MySQL**

- **Modified Solution**

An embedded select with 100 limit and a main select with random 10 limit.

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM employee LIMIT 100) `a` 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10;
```

Or you can create a table where you can store the first 100 rows and select random 10 rows from it.

Like `INSERT INTO tbl2 SELECT * FROM tbl1 LIMIT 100;`.

Then `SELECT * FROM tbl2 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10;`.

- **OLD Solution**

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1 a 
LEFT JOIN tbl1  b ON a.`col1`=b.`col1`
LIMIT 100, 10;
```

Comment: that is 100 records skipping the first 10, but `RAND()` does effectively randomize the selection.

Comment: Yeah your right Sir @DanielFarrell, my first query doesn't really fetch the first 100 rows. It just randomly select 100 rows and fetch 10 rows from that random 100.

Comment: I modified my Solution to this more accurate one.

Comment: NP. But note that the old solution doesn't select the first 100 rows, the solution above selects the first 100 rows.